# What key has dma7-fma7-gma7-Bb?

Tags: chord-progressions, key

I am Trying to figure out what key this chord progression is in. DM7-FM7-GM7-Bb

Comment: this answer (https://music.stackexchange.com/a/106774/70803) will provide the tools you need to figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What keys contain both E and Am and is there an easy trick to determine this?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27179/what-keys-contain-both-e-and-am-and-is-there-an-easy-trick-to-determine-this)

Comment: In any chord sequence, the usual way to determine a key is to decide which chord sounds like the sequence has come to rest, could end on it satisfactorily.

Comment: Why are you asking this question?  So that you can pick one scale to use in improvising over the entire sequence?

Maybe there isn't one.  No one scale that contains the notes of all those chords.   And there doesn't have to be.

Comment: No key has all those chords. But you're not _really_ asking for a key, are you. You're asking for different ways to handle chord progressions like this, right?

Comment: @Alan : this question will soon get closed, because it looks like a key identification question, which is not allowed here. If you could explain what it is that you're actually trying to do and achieve, there might be a plausible question that's allowed to stand. You assumed that if you knew the right key, then it would solve your problem. What is the problem, what is the goal? In what way did you assume that you would utilize the key, if you just knew what it is? Please write a description of the actual task you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

This probably will be closed for being off topic but I will answer because I think I can offer you some information that you will find useful.

No single key has those 4 chords in it. Dmaj7 and Gmaj7 are both part of the key of D major (also B minor). Fmaj7 and Bb are part of D minor, the parallel minor of D major (also F major). That means you can refer to the latter two chords as borrowed chords from the parallel minor, a very common occurrence in all pop styles.

If this progression is a loop that starts and ends on Dmaj7 then it basically is in the key of D but it is a non-diatonic chord progression, meaning it uses chords that are outside of the key.

Regardless of whether a chord progression is diatonic or not the key is usually determined by where the perceived resolution is, or what chord feels like “home”

Comment: This is almost spot on, but I'd add that thinking about switching between D major and D minor is only one of many ways to handle it. You could also e.g. make every chord a full "maj13". Or some other mixture. If you insert an Ebmaj7 chord before it goes back home to Dmaj7, it's kind of like a tritone substitution, but not exactly. And Ebmaj7 is not found in either D major or minor. For this kind of a progression it feels natural to do "chord-scale" thinking, and extend every maj7 chord to some kind of a scale, according to taste.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Everything you say makes sense but based on your other comment you seem to have a different interpretation of the question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I assume the OP is looking for a "strategy" to be able to use the chord progression, but the only thing he's ever heard of is to have something called a key, which to the OP means the same as scale. You present one possible strategy - thinking of the first chord as a tonic and then looking at the other chords and their possible extensions in relation to that centerpoint. I commented here to add some options for doing that.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica What I mean is it’s a simple one sentence question which I answered at face value. You believe the OP is looking for more than what they asked for. The OP has not chimed in since asking the question despite the comments and answers posted. Typical for a 1st timer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *diatonic chords*, only chords matching a key signature? If so, the answer is none.

The quick check of that is look at the chord roots with a *mediant* relationship, meaning that the roots are separated by a third...

`DM7-FM7-GM7-Bb`

...which in that collection of chords would be the `D` & `F` and `G` and `Bb` pairs. Diatonic chords with mediant root relationships *will not be the same quality*. All your chords are *major* in quality, the triad portions are all major triads, therefore they won't all fit one diatonic key signature.

It probably should be noted that there are two pairings of the chords that *do* fit into key signatures. `Dmaj7` and `Gmaj7` fit into `D` major and `Fmaj7` and `Bb` fit into `F` major. Of course those diatonic pairings "interrupt" each other so you never get the feel of one key or the other. In fact, I would say that the overall "effect" or "sound" of the progression is that of *chromatic mediants*, which you might describe as "colorful", "exotic", etc. It's a bit unusual, but still a well know harmonic device.

I suspect there is something more you want to know that what key these chords might have belong to, but you should update your question with those details.

Like some of the commentators I'm guessing you want to "play over" these chords. One diatonic key signature won't match all four chords so you can't just noodle about on a major scale. Some things to try are:

- don't play scales, just arpeggiate the chord tones and use embellishing non-chord tones.
- avoid the notes that have the chromatic *cross relationship* between chords, I'm speaking of the `F/F#`, `B/Bb`, and `C/C#`, which can potentially create some sour dissonances over some of the chords, by process of elimination that leaves tones `D E G A`, which blend fairly un-obnoxiously with all the chords, and form a sort of truncated pentatonic scale, which you could noodle on for a while without become too monotonous.
- look for consecutive thirds that form portions of "scales", ex. alternating `D F#`, `C E`, and `D F#` will match the first two chords `Dmaj7 Fmaj7 Gmaj7` and the `C E` again will work with `Bb` in kind of *lydian* way, the `D F#` and `C E` then create a sort of truncated lydian scale. In a similar way you can match thirds `A F#`, `G E`, `F# D`, `Bb D` to the progression, just add a `C` to that had you have `G` melodic minor/`C` lydian dominant scale, the trick is to understand the progression is not properly in `G` minor, the scale is more of a coincidence, you want to be careful of which portion of the "scale" are matching the various chords.

The progression isn't a "standard" chord progression so you can look for your own way to make sense of things.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say it resolves to Bb. It has the chords built on the 3rd, 5th, 6th and tonic.

Could you give us a link to the context?

Comment: D has F# (and E), G has B natural (and F#), so not too good a match. - Hence the dvs I expect.